# Example of free (finite) group action that is not transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

What is a simple example of a finite group-action, preferably on a set, that is free (semi-regular) but not regular/transitive?

Comment: For a free action which is not transitive : take $X = G' \sqcup G''$ where $G',G''$ are two copies of $G$ and $G$ acts on $X$ with the obvious way. There are two orbits so this is not transitive but this is clear that the action is free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be any group, and let $H$ be a proper subgroup. Now let $H$ act on $G$ by left translation.